# SWIFT - Variable resetting when back from second ViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have been searching for hours here and Google but still didn't find the answer. Everything point to passing variable from a VC to an other but not how to keep variables alive on the VC.

I can pass variables from a VC to an other using multiple methods such as singleton but when I go from second VC to the main VC I'm still facing the same problem.

Exemple you have the main VC which have a label and 2 buttons. When you click one of the button the label text change and then you click the second button to Segue to the second VC. Then when you comeback to the first VC the problem appear: the label is reseted to it's initial text "label". Why?

I tried using global variable in a separate swift file. I said to myself well the value is stored in an other swift file there is no reason why the value of the label reset.. but well it's still resetting.

Thanks so much.

Example in video: https://youtu.be/Wx5blkQqU7E

Very basic example:

varTest.swift

```
import Foundation

var myVar2: String!
```

Main ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mylabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func dsfg(_ sender: UIButton) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "switchForm", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func changeLabeltext(_ sender: UIButton) {


        myVar2 = "Good."
        mylabel.text = myVar2

    }
}
```

Second ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func btnPrint(_ sender: UIButton) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "returnForm", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you maybe reset the text value of the label in your first view controller in `viewWillAppear` method of the first view controller? Can you please share some code from your view controllers?

Comment: Done @MohammedAbdullatif. As you can see this is a very basic test project. IM trying to figure out why the label reinitialize itself to its initial state (text) when I comeback from the second VC

Comment: @MohammedAbdullatif I added a video which you can see at: https://youtu.be/Wx5blkQqU7E

Comment: Are you *unwinding* back to the first VC? Nothing in your code suggest that. EDIT: Segues are merely a kind of visual way to (in a Storyboard) "push and pop" a view controller on to a stack. From the sound of things - and your code suggests it - you are simply pushing VC2 on top of VC1, then pushing a *second* instance of VC1 instead of "popping" VC2 off the stack.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not returning back from `ViewController2` to `ViewController`, but you are pushing a new  `ViewController`, which will display a new UILabel with its default value. You can create an unwind segue from your second view controller to the first view controller, or you can call `dismiss(animated:completion:)` on the second view controller. [This article](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f) can guide you to create an unwind segue.

Comment: Thank you so much I will read on that. This make sense to me. But what is the proper way that all the developers use? unwinding and dismiss ??

Comment: @MohammedAbdullatif I have read about unwind and tested.. works pretty good. I understand now how VC works. Once understood what you said, I first tested with a Navigation Controller which works flawless. Then I made an unwind and its working perfect too. Thanks! You should put your answer as official I will Accept it.

Comment: @MindKind Happy to hear that! I will write my comment as an answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not returning back from `ViewController2` to `ViewController`, but you are pushing a new `ViewController` instance, which will display a new UILabel with its default value. You can create an unwind segue from your second view controller to the first view controller, or you can call dismiss(animated:completion:) on the second view controller. [This article](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f) can guide you to create an unwind segue.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Performing a segue (other than an unwind segue) creates a new instance of the view controller and displays that new instance. It won't have any of the values that were unique to the other instance.

Answer (score 1):

When you "performSegue", the values in the **ViewController** class are reset - don't use segue.

Or alternatively: You mention that you tried to use global variables in a separate swift file. Use a temp file stored on the client side instead.

Use these func to create a file and write to it:

```
//This OVERWRITES already existing files!
func createFileinDocumentDirectory(filename: String){
    let blank = ""
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        do {
            try blank.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Ooooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

func writeToFileInDocumentDirectory(filename: String, textToAdd: String){
    do {
        let dir: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last! as URL
        let url = dir.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        try textToAdd.appendLineToURL(fileURL: url as URL)
    }
    catch {
        print("Could not write to file")
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Can you give an example of doing an "unwind" segue in Storyboards? I think that's the actual answer.